# how to display two charts on one page using angular2

Tags: angular, highcharts

I have two charts that I am trying to load on separate div's on the same page. I tried this code but it doesn't work knowing that when I display one chart in the page it works correctly.
The two code are similar only the data which changes. I think the problem is in the template. Can any one help me to find a solution?
I work with angular2-highchart.

```
 @Component({
 selector: 'chartist-js',
 template: `
 <chart [options]="chartOptions$ | async" style="min-width: 1000px;">
 </chart> <br><chart [options]="chartOptions1$ | async" style="min-
  width: 1000px;"></chart>`,
 providers : [ChartistJsService]
  })
 export class ChartistJs {
 chartOptions$: Observable<any>;
 chartOptions1$: Observable<any>;

 constructor(private dataService: ChartistJsService) {
 this.chartOptions$ = this.dataService.chartData$
 this.chartOptions1$ = this.dataService.chartData$
 .map(data =>
 {this.createChartOptions(data),this.createChartOptions_(data)});
   }

ngOnInit() {
// triggers a fetch of the data to feed the observable
 this.dataService.getData();

   }

 private createChartOptions(data) {
  return {
    chart: {
         type: 'line'
      },
        xAxis: {
          type: 'datetime',
            categories: 
                data.result.map(function (obj) {
                  console.log(obj._id)
                  return obj._id;
                })

        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'ce'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'eddddd',
            data: data.result.map(function (obj) {
              console.log(obj.amount)
return obj.amount; })
                                                                                                  }
        ]

    };
 }

     private createChartOptions_(data) {
     return {
      chart: {
         type: 'line' 
      },
        xAxis: {
          type: 'datetime',
            categories: 
                data.result.map(function (obj) {
                  return obj._id;
                })

        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'sd'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'sdf',
            data: data.result1.map(function (obj) {
            return obj.taux; })                                                                                                      
                }]
       };
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are passing the same observable stream of data into both charts. Somewhere along the way the data might get mutated in each chart - which is why it breaks when you have 2 charts. Each chart is mutating the data and breaking the other. But when there's only 1 chart, it's fine. Try 2 things, first, make a copy of each item in the array before doing anything with it:

```
this.chartOptions$ = this.dataService.chartData$
    .map(data => Object.assign({}, data);
this.chartOptions1$ = this.dataService.chartData$
    .map(data => Object.assign({}, data);
```

If that doesn't work I would try hardcoding 2 completely unrelated objects into 2 charts and seeing if the 2 charts will render. Then you'll know for sure if the sharing is what's causing your problems.